# Colorize material-ui checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

How can I change the background color of an active checkbox when using [material-ui.com-framework](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox)? The style-property has no effect on the svg-color of the checkbox.

```
         <Checkbox
          label="Simple"
         style={styles.checkbox}
       />
```

Comment: To edit the icon in a `Checkbox`, use `iconStyle` prop instead. I don't think you can target the `svg` fill property with regular inline styles. So, I would recommend you to consider using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to give you more power to  customize your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) you can style the components in this way using themes.

You can use predefined themes, or create a [custom theme](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js).
For example, achieving what you want can be as simple as :

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';

const myTheme = getMuiTheme({
    checkbox: { checkedColor: 'red' }
});
```

and then, in the render function you can use the `themeProvider` and pass in your custom theme.This will extend the base theme with the keys you have changed.

```
render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            <Checkbox />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still finding the solution, here is it how it's done.

- Give primary or secondary color to `<CheckBox/>` component.

```
<CheckBox 
color = "primary"
/>
```

- Change primary color of material ui using css:

```
.my-checkbox-wrapper .MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary{
color: 'green';
}
```