# How can i change the color of checkbox in MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik-material-ui

I am trying to change the color of the checkbox of Material UI and I am using FormIk to submit the data. I want to change the default color of the checkbox into red color but I do not know how can I change it.

```
  <FormGroup>
           <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap">
                        {daysOptions.map((day, i) => (
                          <Box key={i}>
                            <Field type="checkbox" name="availability" label={day} value={day} as={Checkbox} />
                          </Box>
                        ))}
                      </Box>
                    </FormGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Check these. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202757/colorize-material-ui-checkbox
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970631/change-the-tick-color-in-muicheckbox-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

**Using withstyles**

1. Import **Checkbox** (*checkbox itself*) and **FormControlLabel** (*for name of the checkbox*) from Material UI

> ```
> import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
> import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
> ```

2. Import **withstyles** to customize the color and the color **red**

> ```
> import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
> import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
> ```

3. Customize using withstyles

> ```
> const RedCheckbox = withStyles({
>   root: {
>     color: red[900],
>     '&$checked': {
>       color: red[200],
>     },
>   },
>   checked: {},
> })((props) => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
> ```

4. Add `Redcheckbox` (*or the name that you assigned*) inside the FormControlLabel

> ```
> <FormControlLabel
>       control={
>         <RedCheckbox
>           checked={state.checkedA}
>           onChange={handleChange}
>           name="checkedA"
>         />
>       }
>       label="Monday"
>  />
> ```

Follow This [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-xrfy8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for the complete code.
(open the demo.js file)

If you don't like the color they offer, you can also customize their color palette.
to do that, please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70430903/16056064)

feel free to comment if you need help.

Link to the MUI checkbox component ->
https://v4.mui.com/components/checkboxes/#checkbox

Comment: I tried using FormControlLabel but then my data is not stored in the database. That's why I am using Field component.

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite catch your problem. If helps, you can always pass a  string variable to the "label" property inside the "FormControlLabel".